# Why does Chrome show me a 200 Temporary Redirect status code?

Tags: http, webforms, http-status-codes

We're witnessing a strange behavior when trying to load a site that is behind a waf. There's a couple of misterious redirects, but one of them caught my eye: it has a 200 Temporary Redirect Status Code:

[image]

What does this Temporary Redirect really mean?

Thanks.

Comment: It is the same situation in Chrome v120

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an internal redirect HTTP to HTTPS or protocol upgrade.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: But don't we have 3xx for that?